# Cakephp using group by in find method

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm trying to use Group by in find method for my relational database I want to get the latest record with unique receiver_id out of result set filtered by user_id and below is my code:

```
$this->loadModel('Chat');
        $lastChat = $this->Chat->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Chat.user_id' => $user_id['User']['id']
            ),
            'fields' => array(
                'Chat.id',
                'Chat.chat',
                'Chat.user_id',
                'Chat.receiver_id',
                'Chat.read',
                'Chat.created'
            ),
            'group' => array('Chat.receiver_id'),
            'order' => array('Chat.created DESC')
        ));
```

However, this does not seem to work. I'm not sure why but I'm only getting one result...

How can I get multiple results with rules based on above.

Comment: Looks fine to me. I suggest you try to find out if $user_id really consists of what you think it would.

Comment: have you print the query it generates? maybe looking to the sql you may see your mistake. To do that just change find for a getQuery and print lastchat. try using a `select * from Chats where user_id = $userid` to see if it gives you more results.

Comment: like api55 said, show us the query it's generating - much easier to help you then.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$db = $this->Chat->getDataSource();
$chats = $db->query("SELECT * , (Chat.user_id + Chat.receiver_id) AS dist
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM  chats t
        WHERE ( t.user_id =$id OR t.receiver_id =$id )
        ORDER BY t.id DESC
    ) Chat
    GROUP BY dist
    ORDER BY Chat.id DESC");
```